# Determining if one of the two strings is a substring of the other String Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have two text fields where the user can enter any text.

One field can have: `The sky is blue.`
Second field have: `The ocean is blue.`

In Javascript what is the easiest way to check if one string entered in one field is a substring for the other field?

So far this is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Substring Test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript"> 

         function displayContent() {
         var contentEntered = document.getElementById("userContent").value; 
         var contentEnteredSecond = document.getElementById("secondUserContent").value;
               document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p> The content entered was " + contentEntered + " </p>"; 
               document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p> The content entered was " + contentEnteredSecond + " </p>"; 
         }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Substring</h1>
      <div id="mainCont">
         <p>Please enter any content.</p>
         <p>Content:
            <input type="text" id="userContent">
         </p>
         <p>Content:
            <input type="text" id="secondUserContent">
         </p>
         <p>
            <input type="button" onclick="displayContent();" value="Submit">
         </p>
         <div id="result"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right here: `.indexOf`

Comment: `bigstring.indexOf(smallerstring) >= 0`

Comment: @HunanRostomyan No. Please don't randomly mark questions as duplicate of unrelated questions.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Of course. Sorry. That was obviously unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkSub(str1, str2){

    if(str1.indexOf(str2) > -1 || str2.indexOf(str1) > -1) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Uh... `return (str1.indexOf(str2) > -1 || str2.indexOf(str1) > -1);` might be better ;)

Comment: @RickHitchcock no it is not. It is checking the presence of the each string in the each other string.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes, but the code should be more readable according to me.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that and upvoted.  I was thinking `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: @void True, but `return true; else return false;` gives me an eye sore.. it's just a personal preference I guess.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yeah true.

Comment: so basically it's comparing each characters of the strings checking if there are any similarities else if not then there are none?

Comment: No, it is checking either str2 contains str1 or other way round.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 it's simple with [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
str1.includes(str2) || str2.includes(str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`includes`](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) function from [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs) library.

```
function checkSubstr(str1, str2) {
    return _.includes(str1, str2) || _.includes(str2, str1);
}
```